# can we declare size of a pointer

Tags: c++, string, pointers

can we declare size to a pointer

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char (*ptr)=new char[3];
strcpy(ptr,"ert");
cout<<ptr<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

what is the meaning of this line char *ptr=new char[3]  if it allocates size to ptr.since i have given the size as 3 and the string as "ert"it has to show error since the string length is too long but it doesn't .can we allocate size to pointers if so how?

Comment: `"ert"` actually holds 4 `char`'s. There's an extra nul terminating at the end.

Comment: The best you can do is use things like `strncpy`

Comment: it doesn't have to show error since it doesn't know how many bytes you allocated at run time.

Comment: can u explain in detail . i said that the compiler is not showing error since i have given the length only 3 but the actual size is 4

Comment: strcpy, "string copy", c++ has std::string but it still has c strings in it, which are basically an array of characters ending with '\0' (ASCII 0 - null terminator). Thus, using strcpy this way will enter 4 characters - 'e', 'r', 't' and '\0' to indicate the end of the string.

Comment: some really smart compilers will give you a warning, but all compilers i know will let it pass.  this is because it is legit c++ code.

Comment: @PeterT `strncpy` is never a good idea, it just replaces one problem with another

Comment: @benny, I rolled back your edit, please don't change to a completely different question after it has been answered

Answer (score 1):

You need `4` characters:

```
char *ptr=new char[4];
strcpy(ptr,"ert");
```

One extra space for the [nul terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string):

```
|e|r|t|\0|
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
char (*ptr)=new char[3];
```

at first allocates in the heap unnamed character array with 3 elements and then the address of the first element of the array is assigned to pointer ptr.

The size of the pointer will not be changed whether you initialize it as in the statement above or the following way

```
char (*ptr)=new char;
```

that is `sizeof( ptr )` will be the same and equal usually either to 4 or 8 bytes depending on the environment where the program will be compiled.

C++ does not check bounds of arrays. So in this statement

```
strcpy(ptr,"ert");
```

you have undefined behaviour of the program because string literal `"ert"` has four elements including the terminating zero.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the size of the pointer that you've declared, but the size of the character array that the pointer points to.

`strcpy()` does not know the length of the array that the pointer points to - it just knows it's got a pointer to the first byte it can copy into, and trusts that you know there's enough room for the copy to be made. Thus it's very fast, but it's also rather dangerous and should be used only when you're sure the destination is large enough.

`strncpy()` is worth looking into for some extra safety, but you still have to know that the target pointer points to something large enough for the size you specify (it protects more against the size of the source than the size of the target).

The lesson to learn here is that C and C++ won't give you any help - the compiler trusts you to get your buffer sizes right, and won't do any checking on your behalf either at compile time or runtime. This allows programs to run extremely fast (no runtime checking) but also requires the programmer to be a lot more careful. If you're writing in C++ which your tags suggest, for normal string handling you should definitely be using the `std::string` class unless you have a specific reason to need C-style string handling. You may well have such a reason from time to time, but don't do it unless you have to.

Comment: The compiler's perfectly entitled to diagnose this error ... most of them don't bother. Feel free to join the gcc team and add in a diagnostic here!

Comment: `strncpy` is not a safe function to use here, it just replaces one buffer overflow with another

Comment: Indeed `strncpy` is not of much help in this situation really. There's not much that is other than changing to a language which doesn't fall victim to this kind of thing. And I suspect that's slightly out of scope :)